# Apache - Dynamic ErrorLog and CustomLog with VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, error-log

My dynamic VirtualHosts are working fine on CentOS 6.5 and httpd 2.2.15.
I can access my websites http://foo.dev.com and http://bar.dev.com.
The problem is that I don't have dynamic CustomLog and ErrorLog.

/etc/httpd/conf.d/dev.com.conf:

```
UseCanonicalName Off

NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/home/username/PHP/%0/public_html/"
    <Directory "/home/username/PHP/%0/public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Directory structure:

```
/home
    /username
        /PHP
            /foo.dev.com
                /public_html
                /logs
            /bar.dev.com
                /public_html
                /logs
```

I've tried:

```
    ...

    CustomLog "/home/username/PHP/%{HTTP_HOST}/logs/access_log" combined
    ErrorLog "/home/username/PHP/%{HTTP_HOST}/logs/error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

and got the following error:

```
(2)No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file /home/username/PHP/%{HTTP_HOST}/logs/error_log
Unable to open logs
```

and also:

```
    ...

    CustomLog "/home/username/PHP/%0/logs/access_log" combined
    ErrorLog "/home/username/PHP/%0/logs/error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

with the following error:

```
(2)No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file /home/username/PHP/%0/logs/error_log.
Unable to open logs
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths for the *Log directives? According to docs, a relative path is considered relative to the ServerRoot.

Comment: CBroe, how? Do you have any resource? I'm not an Apache expert ... Thanks.

Comment: But you _do_ know what a relative path is, don’t you …? (If not, stop messing with server configuration I’d say.)

Comment: Yes, I do know what relative path means. I asked about a resource or example. Could you please provide some? Thank you very much!

Comment: Resource for what? Where it says how paths for `CustomLog`/`ErrorLog` are handled? See apache manual.

Comment: Relative paths doesn't work: "(2)No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file /etc/logs/error_log. Unable to open logs". It seems to be relative to /etc/httpd/ ...